# Is there a formula that will count the number of terms in a mathematical equation in Google Sheets or Excel?

Tags: excel-formula, sum, google-sheets-formula, string-formatting, google-query-language

I use Google Sheets to keep track of how I spend my time at work. One of those tasks is email. I want to know how many times I check my email and how much time it takes out of my day.

Currently if I checked it four times during the day, I enter `Email|4` in Column D, and then, e.g. `=3+2+5+1` in Column E.

If I want to analyze the cumulative data, the pipe character lets me use a formula to get that "4" out of the cell in D, but I would rather not have to enter it at all.

Is there a formula that will look at the cell in Column E and return the number of terms being added together? So, if E28 is `=4+1+2+3+1` it would return "5"?

I will be starting a new job soon and building a new spreadsheet, so I can switch to Excel if that would provide functionality that GSheets doesn't.

Comment: `=1+LEN(FORMULATEXT(E28))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(E28),"+",""))`

Comment: Nice solution provided that it's always `+`. Else use something like `=1+SUM(LEN(FORMULATEXT(C10))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(C10),{"+","-","*","/"},"")))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=COLUMNS(SPLIT(A1; "+"))
```

[image]

or if your cell is `11`:

```
=COLUMNS(SPLIT(FORMULATEXT(A5), "+"))
```

[image]